# How can I create a number of random values within a certain range that sums up to 1?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, constraints

I want to create 9 random values that sum up to 1. each of the 9 values have to be within a specific range that is stored in array `s`

```
s = np.array([
       [0.1 , 0.3 ],
       [0.05, 0.2 ],
       [0.15, 0.2 ],
       [0.15, 0.3 ],
       [0.05, 0.15],
       [0.07, 0.15],
       [0.1 , 0.2 ],
       [0.05, 0.15],
       [0.01, 0.1 ]])
```

In array `s` the first column is the lower bound of the range and the second column the highest bound. hence the first value of the 9 has to fall between 0.1 and 0.3, the second between 0.05 and 0.2 etc. in such a way that all the values sum up to 1.

This is my latest try

```
def randomtosum(ranges, total):
    result = []
    for x, y in ranges:
        result.append(random.uniform(x,y))
    result.append(total - sum(result))
    return result

r = randomtosum(s,1)
```

but this always creates a 10th negative value...

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your application? Why are you solving this problem? Can you please give some context?

You mention that the values should be "random", but do not mention further properties. For example, you have the first range 0.1–0.3...is it okay if the value *never* has a chance of being 0.3? Is it okay if all of the values are correlated, e.g. if they're all small or all large, never an unpredictable mix? "Random" does not constrain the problem much, is that your intent?

The best way to capture your requirements is to include direct requirements and your application (what this is for).

Comment: I think that your constrains are hard to meet, for instance, you may get the first 5 numbers as 0.29, 0.19, 0.19, 0.29, 0.1 because they all meet the ranges but they already sum 1.06.

Comment: The sum of the first eight lower bounds is `0.72`. So for that *minimum* case, the ninth value would have to be `0.28` - but the upper bound is only `0.1`. And there's a similar problem with the first seven values...

Comment: maybe I have to adjust my constraints. the main idea is that I need to use the values as weights so show the importance of other values. I already have a set of weights that add to 1 but I want to see whether the distribution of those values between 0 and 1 influences my results (I use the weights to multiply other values by). however, I don't want completely randomly selected values between 0 and 1 as there should still be some human influence.

Comment: Wouldn't it be reasonable to expect that not all your numbers can be random due to this particular constraint?

Comment: @Judith How exactly did you arrive at the bounds for each value?

Answer (score 0):

A short, hacky way is to use your "total - sum" value as last value and check, if it fits the boundaries, if not, try again the whole list:

```
import numpy as np
import random

s = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.3],
    [0.05, 0.2],
    [0.15, 0.2],
    [0.15, 0.3],
    [0.05, 0.15],
    [0.07, 0.15],
    [0.1, 0.2],
    [0.05, 0.15],
    [0.01, 0.1]])


def is_possible(ranges, total) -> bool:
    mins = 0
    maxs = 0
    for x, y in ranges:
        mins += x
        maxs += y

    return mins < total < maxs


def randomtosum(ranges, total) -> list:
    if is_possible(ranges, total):
        return get_randomtosum(ranges, total)
    else:
        return []


def get_randomtosum(ranges, total) -> list:
    result = []
    for x, y in ranges[:-1]:
        result.append(random.uniform(x, y))
    tmp = total - sum(result)
    if ranges[-1][0] < tmp < ranges[-1][1]:
        result.append(tmp)
        return result
    else:
        return randomtosum(ranges, total)


r = randomtosum(s, 1)

print(r)
```

Comment: Thank you this works sometimes, but unfortunately doesn't always seem to return a set of random values.

Comment: yes, this is beacuse it is a try and error approach, so it could find an solution, but only tries 100 time (you could increase the maxvalue). But i added an other solution, to check, if it is possible and than use the try error approach, so it should always return values, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
import numpy as np
import random
s = np.array([
       [0.1 , 0.3 ],
       [0.05, 0.2 ],
       [0.15, 0.2 ],
       [0.15, 0.3 ],
       [0.05, 0.15],
       [0.07, 0.15],
       [0.1 , 0.2 ],
       [0.05, 0.15],
       [0.01, 0.1 ]])

raw_rands = [random.uniform(x,y) for x,y in s]

while sum(raw_rands) >= 1: 
  raw_rands = [random.uniform(x,y) for x,y in s]
```

if the idea of a while loop running until it meet the condition scares you as much as it scares me, you could try a for using a range that limit the number of iterations.

```
raw_rands = [random.uniform(x,y) for x,y in s]

for i in range(1000):
  if sum(raw_rands) <= 1:
    break
  new_raw_rands = [random.uniform(x,y) for x,y in s]
  if sum(new_raw_rands) < sum(raw_rands):
    raw_rands = [random.uniform(x,y) for x,y in s]
```

If it doesn't get the random variables sum less or equal than 1 at least it will get the iteration with the least sum value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the individual ranges to weight the random numbers.
Normalise to 1-the sum of the lows.
Add to the lows.

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([
       [0.1 , 0.3 ],
       [0.05, 0.2 ],
       [0.15, 0.2 ],
       [0.15, 0.3 ],
       [0.05, 0.15],
       [0.07, 0.15],
       [0.1 , 0.2 ],
       [0.05, 0.15],
       [0.01, 0.1 ]])

low = s[ :, 0]           # Array of low limits
rng = s[ :, 1] - low    # Array of the range of each row

free = 1.0 - low.sum()   # the free value in play 1 - sum lo

np.random.seed( 1234 )  # Make reproducable, remove in real version.

rnd = np.random.random( size = len(rng)) * rng # random weighted by the ranges

rnd = rnd * free / rnd.sum()    # Normalise to free

result = low + rnd

print( result, 'Sum ', result.sum() )

# [0.11829863 0.09457931 0.16045562 0.20627753 0.08726121 
#  0.08041789 0.11320732 0.08830725 0.05119523] Sum  1.0
```

Making this a function.

```
def sum_to_one( s ):
    low = s[ :, 0]           # Array of low limits
    rng = s[ :, 1] - low    # Array of the range of each row
    free = 1.0 - low.sum()   # the free value in play 1 - sum lo
    rnd = np.random.random( size = len(rng)) * rng # random weighted by the ranges
    rnd = rnd * free / rnd.sum()    # Normalise to free
    return low + rnd
```